# Carrierwave cached image not being stored after failed validations - nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, carrierwave

I have spent at least two days trying to resolve this issue over the last few weeks and really could do with a little direction as I feel like I have gone through all of the similar problems listed here and elsewhere.

I have Carrierwave setup for Image uploading using model associations and a nested form, it works fine. Images can be uploaded and updated. When I change the image on a Post AND cause the forms validation to fail, the images cache value is set (confirmed by the **upload_filename_cache=(text)** method I added into PostMediaUpload), the cache value is placed inside the hidden field on the form and the file is stored in the tmp directory.

When I resubmit the form with a passing validation, nothing seems to happen with the cached value - no errors, the old image is still present. I have tried to include as much information as possible.. I'm hoping this is something simple as everything seems to work as intended apart from the final step of uploading the cached version.

Below is a simplified version of my models:

**Post**

```
has_one :post_media_upload, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_media_upload, \
    :reject_if => proc {|attributes| attributes['upload_filename'].blank? \
    && attributes['upload_filename_cache'].blank?}
```

**Post Media Upload**

```
class PostMediaUpload < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :post

  mount_uploader :upload_filename, PostImageUploader

  validate :file_size_check

  def upload_filename_cache=(text)

    if upload_filename_cache
      byebug
      # TODO: We have a cached file, it exists in the hidden form field and the tmp/uploads folder
      # On successful form validation, the cached version isn't uploaded to S3 / set to upload_filename.
      #upload_filename = nil
      #changed_attributes.merge!("upload_filename" => nil)
    end

    super
  end

  private

    def file_size_check
      if upload_filename.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:file_size, "should be less than 5MB")
      end
    end

end
```

**Post Media Upload Schema**

```
create_table "post_media_uploads", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer  "post_id",        null: false
        t.string   "upload_filename",   null: false
        t.string   "original_filename", null: false
        t.string   "media_type",        null: false
        t.integer  "file_size",         null: false
        t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
        t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_post_media_uploads_on_post_id", using: :btree
      end
```

**PostImageUploader**

```
class PostImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Save Original File Name
  before :cache, :save_original_filename_and_data

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/posts/#{model.post_id}"
  end

  # Alter File Name to be Unique
  def filename
    "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end

  # White list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end

  def fog_public
    false
  end

  def fog_authenticated_url_expiration
    5.minutes # in seconds from now,  (default is 10.minutes)
  end

  version :large do
    process resize_to_limit: [800, 800]
  end

  version :medium, :from_version => :large do
    process resize_to_limit: [500, 500]
  end

  version :thumb, :from_version => :medium do
    process resize_to_fit: [100, 100]
  end

  version :square do
    process :resize_to_fit => [300, nil]
  end

  protected
    def save_original_filename_and_data(file)
      model.original_filename ||= file.original_filename if file.respond_to?(:original_filename)
      model.media_type = file.content_type
      model.file_size = file.size
    end

    def secure_token
      var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
      model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join))
    end

end
```

**Post Form**

```
<%= f.fields_for :post_media_upload do |h| %>
  Browse&hellip; <%= h.file_field :upload_filename, :multiple => false, :style => "display: none;", :onchange => "validateImageUpload(this);" %>
  <%= h.hidden_field :upload_filename_cache, :value => post.post_media_upload.upload_filename_cache %>
<% end %>
```

**Post White listed Params**

```
def post_params

  params.require(:post).permit(:title, ..omitted..
                     :is_private, post_media_upload_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :upload_filename, :upload_filename_cache] )

end
```

**Post Update Action**

```
if @post.update(post_params)
    @post.set_pending_changes
    redirect_to account_post_path(@post), notice: 'Your post was updated successfully'
else
    # Build Nested Resource if not present
    @post.build_post_media_upload unless @post.post_media_upload.present?
    render :edit
end
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is anybody able to assist me with this issue? I don't think I can add any additional clarification, if I can - please let me know.

Comment: did you get a solution? I've got the same problem, driving me nuts.